# Jquery UI draggable stop: поймать элемент который находится под тем,который перетягивают

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Собственно говоря, вопрос в заголовке. Что я хочу сделать, но не знаю как: при срабатывании event stop получить элемент, над которым отпустили блок, далее обработать по скрипту. Есть функция, которая выбирает все элементы по указанным осям(по факту, каждый раз в разных координатах по оси x, но в пределах ширины блока, который перетягивают). Код привожу:

```
function allElementsFromPoint(x, y) {
       var element, elements = [];
        var old_visibility = [];
        while (true) {
            element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
            if (!element || element === document.documentElement) {
                break;
            }
            elements.push(element);
            old_visibility.push(element.style.visibility);
            element.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // Temporarily hide the element (without changing the layout)
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < elements.length; k++) {
            elements[k].style.visibility = old_visibility[k];
        }
        elements.reverse();
        return elements;
    }
```

Возможно, я не в правильном направлении вообще иду? Для чего это все нужно: есть месячная шкала, есть периоды. Периоды можна перетягивать между месяцами. Нужно поймать блок, где остановится период и взять с него дату нового периода: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: document.elementFromPoint - попробуйте

Comment: @Дмытрык , данный код есть уже в функции. Проблема в том,что она выбирает элементы в пределах периода..

Comment: решение в лоб: пока не найдете нужный элемент, в цикле, вычислять местоположение каждого элемента периода, сравнивая его с позицией перетаскиваемого элемента

Comment: @Дмытрык , пока единственный вариант